# a recommended subtitle editor for ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, video, subtitle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What program to use to create subtitles for a video?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24059/what-program-to-use-to-create-subtitles-for-a-video)

When I was using windows, I used to edit subtitles with Subtitle Workshop which is a quite good.

Does anyone can recommend about a good subtitle editor for ubuntu?