# Can I directly download audio using youtube-dl?

Tags: youtube-dl

Can I *directly* download audio from a YouTube video instead of first downloading audio+video and then extracting the audio?

Comment: I don't think its a duplicate because that question clearly required the search facility. This question does not. I have also mentioned that in the answer. This question is useflu to people who already know what has to be downloaded.

Comment: The same answer there is applicable her

Comment: Which answer? Can you give the link?

Comment: @blade answer you can check it

Comment: That answer has to download the video first. This question and answer (1) does not want downloading of the video (2) does not want to search YouTube. I hope you understand.

Comment: If you want to download only audio you can do it with your answer on that question... Have you tried ur answer before answering me?!

Comment: That does not use youtube-dl. It uses another program called `mps-youtube`. Correct? This question is about using `youtube-dl` and not about using  `mps-youtube`. I always try my answers myself before posting. If I don't, I will make it clear that it is only a suggestion :)

Comment: The answer is in the comment to blade answer. Just no. You can't use youtube-dl to do it.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. You can use `youtube-dl` to do this, but I can't answer this question because people have marked this as a duplicate.

Comment: I have developed little tool called youtuber  https://github.com/maythamfahmi/YouTuber/releases

Comment: Most important question of our time. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search and download audio-only from youtube](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420857/search-and-download-audio-only-from-youtube)

Comment: This answer from a duplicate question is also quite good: https://askubuntu.com/a/634622

Answer (score 266, accepted):

Here is a recent article in webupd8.org that explains how to use `youtube-dl` to directly download audio instead of first downloading video+audio and then extracting audio using `-x`. *Unfortunately, the search facility that [Maythux](https://askubuntu.com/users/150504/maythux) asked for [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/420857/248158) isn't offered.* But it is still worth a look:
[Video Downloader `youtube-dl` Gets Support For Separate Audio And Video YouTube DASH Streams](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/02/video-downloader-youtube-dl-gets.html)

Basically, download the latest version of youtube-dl [from source](http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/download.html) or from the ppa offered in the link above but **not** from the Software Center.

Then, if you already have the video link ...

Run, as example:

```
youtube-dl -F 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HRIF4_WzU1w'
```

This will list the various download formats available for this url (audio and video).

```
$ youtube-dl -F 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HRIF4_WzU1w'
[youtube] Setting language
[youtube] HRIF4_WzU1w: Downloading webpage
[youtube] HRIF4_WzU1w: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] HRIF4_WzU1w: Extracting video information
[info] Available formats for HRIF4_WzU1w:
format code extension resolution  note 
171         webm      audio only  DASH webm audio , audio@ 48k (worst)
140         m4a       audio only  DASH audio , audio@128k
160         mp4       192p        DASH video 
133         mp4       240p        DASH video 
134         mp4       360p        DASH video 
135         mp4       480p        DASH video 
17          3gp       176x144     
36          3gp       320x240     
5           flv       400x240     
43          webm      640x360     
18          mp4       640x360     (best)
```

Now, choose desired audio format. I went for `140`

Run:

```
youtube-dl -f 140 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HRIF4_WzU1w'

$ youtube-dl -f 140 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HRIF4_WzU1w'
[youtube] Setting language
[youtube] HRIF4_WzU1w: Downloading webpage
[youtube] HRIF4_WzU1w: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] HRIF4_WzU1w: Extracting video information
[download] Destination: Martin Luther King - I Have a Dream on August 28, 1963 [Sous-titres & Subtitles] [FULL SPEECH]-HRIF4_WzU1w.m4a
[download] 100% of 15.19MiB in 00:04
```

That's it.

Comment: Some audio players do not support DASH audio. For m4a, I had to demux it to make it a 'regular' m4a using ffmpeg. For example: `ffmpeg -i input.m4a -vn -c:a copy output.m4a`

Comment: @sunk818 and just a public announcement that: `youtube-dl 2015.01.23.4 and newer will automatically correct the header of the m4a file if ffmpeg is present on the system.` So, if `ffmpeg` is installed before `youtube-dl` is called now it will automatically fix the DASH container and you won't need to run sunk818's fix.

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with that fix. Another youtube-dl user and I posted an issue, one of the youtube-dl coders read it, and put in an enhancement for us.

Comment: `youtube-dl -f bestaudio http://...` if you don't want to select best audio manually.

Comment: be careful with `-f bestaudio` as best audio could be .webm and not .m4a Use -f m4a if you want best m4a quality audio.

Comment: @Sun why m4a is better than webm? and why would the latter be chosen as best audio if it's not? did you report it as a bug to youtube-dl devs?

Comment: Please re read my comment. I don't day one is better than another

Comment: `youtube-dl -f 'bestaudio[ext=m4a]' "http://youtu.be/hTvJoYnpeRQ"`

Comment: Can someone verify that`-f 'bestaudio[ext=m4a]'` is always equal to `-f 140`, as I haven't come across some videos containing an .m4a that is higher than 128 kbps.

Comment: It no longer works with -F <number> as of the current version 20.2.4 - gives an error that -F is not a valid URL. @PabloBianchi 's answer below works though

Comment: `webm` can be both `audio` and `video`. Default download is `video`.

Comment: @Andrey Bash is case sensitive. Use the capital `-F` with no number to list available formats. Use the lowercase `-f` with a number to specify the format.

Answer (score 97):

From [@xiota's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/423508/can-i-directly-download-audio-using-youtube-dl#comment1681760_423510), to download the best audio in m4a format:

```
$ youtube-dl -f 'bestaudio[ext=m4a]' 'http://youtu.be/hTvJoYnpeRQ'
```

<sup>I've missed it on the first reading, so I've decided to post the comment as an answer to make it more visible.</sup>

Comment: This gives 2 errors, one for format not available and the other for failing to parse the url,

Comment: @AtteJuvonen the command works as is.

Comment: No it doesn't. WARNING: The url doesn't specify the protocol, trying with http ... Warning: Could not send HEAD request to http://'http://youtu.be/hTvJoYnpeRQ'. If I fix the url by removing the ' characters, then it gives ERROR: requested format not available.

Comment: @AtteJuvonen try to copy the command *as is* If it is still failing for you, provide your OS, youtube-dl version.

Comment: I'm on Windows 10, youtube-dl version 2018.11.07

Comment: @AtteJuvonen the site is "Ask Ubuntu". I tested the command on Ubuntu.  Ubuntu is different from Windows. The command in the answer expects a bash-like shell. On Windows, for `cmd.exe` you could try to replace single quotes with doubles quotes (there could be other Windows related issues).

Comment: That's faster. [Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/644155/341192)'s how to make it even more so: (#1) `bash -c 'printf "%s" "youtube-dl -f bestaudio[ext=m4a]" | xsel -b' && konsole`  copies to clipboard the necessary command and opens a terminal where (#2) it can be pasted, thus putting forth a window for you to add the youtube link with another (#3)copy+(#4)paste -- or maybe just *one* drag & drop (that's #3), followed by (#4/5) Enter. A total of 4 or 5 keyboard & mouse actions without the need for actually writing anything.

Answer (score 32):

This alias let me easily download any audio with better filenames:

```sh
$ alias | grep audio

alias yt-dl-audio='yt-dlp --ignore-errors --output "%(title)s.%(ext)s" --extract-audio --audio-format mp3'
```

I switched from youtube-dl to [**yt-dlp**](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/). Works faster and includes things like `--split-chapters`. Most things are equivalent.

**About audio quality**: From the [documentation](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#format-selection): *"By default yt-dlp/youtube-dl tries to download the best available quality, i.e., if you want the best quality you don't need to pass any special options, yt-dlp will guess it for you by default."*. So there's no need for `--audio-quality 0` or `-f bestaudio`.

**About Updates**: [Download last version of yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/wiki/Installation#using-the-release-binary). **Avoid repo, PPA version [or pip/pipx](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2023/03/next-debianubuntu-releases-will-likely.html)** so you can upgrade with `yt-dlp -U` (necessary quite often).

> To install it right away for all UNIX users (Linux, OS X, etc.), type:
>
> ```
> sudo curl -L https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/releases/latest/download/yt-dlp -o /usr/local/bin/yt-dlp
> sudo chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/yt-dlp  # Make executable
> ```

**Albums** (or compilations, mashups, etc.): You can split the file into chunks/tracks [with `mp3split`](https://askubuntu.com/a/27637/349837). To generate the playlist timestamps (like the ones found on YouTube comments) and track count:

```sh
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -af silencedetect=n=-40dB:d=2.7 -f null - |& awk '/silence_end/ {print $4,$5}' | awk '{S=$2;printf "%d:%02d:%02d\n",S/(60*60),S%(60*60)/60,S%60}' | tee >(wc -l)  # Play with tolerance (n/noise threshold level) and duration on silencedetect. More: `ffmpeg -h filter=silencedetect`.
```

Please leave a comment if you found a better approach, maybe something using [MusicBrainz](https://musicbrainz.org/).

#### Common problems

- **Error 403?** [Add `--rm-cache-dir`](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/24794#issuecomment-613891560).
- **Stuck at "Downloading webpage"?** [Add `--force-ipv4`](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/26038#issuecomment-663976507).

#### Alternatives and other notes

- [**ytmdl**](https://github.com/deepjyoti30/ytmdl): *A simple script to get songs from YouTube in mp3 format with all tags from iTunes*.
- To download in batch from a plain text, [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/878922/349837).
- **MP3 Tagging**: I’m still trying to find a reliable CLI tool to fix and tag all the generated mp3:

  - [Beets](http://beets.io/) (maybe with [tracker](https://gnome.pages.gitlab.gnome.org/tracker/faq/#can-tracker-help-me-organize-my-music-collection) [cheatsheet](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Music/Resources#Tracker_cheatsheet) and [gnome-music](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Music/)?)
  - [lltag](http://bgoglin.free.fr/lltag/)
  - [foobar2000](https://github.com/mmtrt/foobar2000)