# How to download a format that has audio by itself in youtube-dl?

Tags: youtube-dl

I want to start watching the downloading file immediately, so if youtube-dl downloads video and audio separately I'll be foiled. I.e, I want youtube-dl to choose the best format that has both video and audio.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I directly download audio using youtube-dl?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/423508/can-i-directly-download-audio-using-youtube-dl)

Comment: `youtube-dl -f 'bestaudio[ext=m4a]' "http://youtu.be/hTvJoYnpeRQ"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [project's README](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#readme):

> If you want to preserve the old format selection behavior (prior to youtube-dl 2015.04.26), i.e. you want to download the best available quality media **served as a single file**, you should explicitly specify your choice with `-f best`.