# Edit the default list of plasma clipboard actions

Tags: kubuntu, clipboard, 22.10

[image]

That appears when copying a URL or file if the option "Include MIME actions" is enabled in clipboard actions settings:

[image]

New actions can be added, I want to try that, but for the moment the default list is not based on the list in that setting, which is empty:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have understood more about what this popup does. The clipboard actions are related to paths, starting with `file://` or `http` (that is files, folders and URLs) to show the applications (as well as other actions that can be added in settings) associated with these elements (mime types).

Therefore, what is seen in the image of that list in the question relates strictly to applications associated to a URL/HTML document, so that it is the same as that of the "Open with" context menu list for an HTML document:

[image]

Plus, it may contain actions that can be added in the clipboard settings

[image]

[image]

Therefore, the answer is that *the list can be edited by changing the list of associated applications (in a file's properties or in the system settings for file association) and by adding new clipboard actions in the clipboard settings*.

---

Supplementary tip:

I have noticed that new clipboard actions as such are not even needed for (at least some) new operations, because the same result can be achieved with a new associated application.

For example, the action in the image above, with the command `bash -c 'mpv %s'` can be replaced by just adding the `mpv` player as associated application for that type of file:

[image]

Variables can be added to associated applications in the same way:

[image]

Also, it must be noted that, by default, in Firefox the normal behavior of showing the list when copying a URL [is absent (but can be enabled](https://askubuntu.com/q/1445714/925128): see the answer at link. There is also, as a general solution, the possibility to enable/associate a shortcut for that list in the clipboard settings -"Open Klipper at Mouse position":

[image]

Then, after copying the link in Firefox, press that shortcut and the list of clipboard actions should appear. (This workaround was documented before I had the answer to the linked question.)

---

Also, it has to be noted that in order to send a such path to clipboard simply selecting/highlighting the path can be enough if the specific setting is enabled in clipboard options:

[image]